# php artisan clear-compiled error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have just started working on a project again for the first time in 6 months and it was all going very well until I did a `composer update` and I received the following error:

```
vagrant@default:/vagrant$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive() in /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 213



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                        
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive()  



Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                       
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive() in /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Suppo  
  rt/Facades/Facade.php on line 213                                                                                                                                        


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I then tried running `php artisan clear-compiled` and got this:

```
vagrant@default:/vagrant$ php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive() in /vagrant/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 213



  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                        
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::directive()
```

I am running the following:

```
vagrant@default:/vagrant$ php --version
PHP 5.6.17-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+2 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

I have read many questions about this which all seem to have been resolved by deleting a file called either `compiled.php`or `compile.php` or something in both the `storage` and `vendor` folders, however, I do not have these files in my system.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue of using a package that does not support your version of laravel. see these for example: github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/issues/66 https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-artisan-call-to-undefind-method

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not fix the issue. I just tried re-cloning and reinstalling the app. If I `composer install` all is well, if I `composer update` the error re-appears.

Comment: @atwright147 This may be an issue of using a package that does not support your version of laravel.  see here: https://github.com/kodeine/laravel-acl/issues/66 and here https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/php-artisan-call-to-undefind-method

Comment: Wahoo! It was **edvinaskrucas/notification**, 5.0 is compatible with Laravel 5.0, 5.1 is not. I had to change from `"edvinaskrucas/notification": "^5.0",` to `"edvinaskrucas/notification": "5.0.0",`. @Jeff: write this as an answer and I will mark it as THE answer :) Thank you!

Comment: @atwright147 I edited my answer to give this response :)